# Variable being multipled for no apparent reason

Tags: php

I made a pic of the code vs. what comes out. Is there anything else I need to show? Why is this happening?

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X798O.png)

Comment: Hi Neo Chen, Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read the article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and follow it's principles. For further help, please provide your source code in a working snippet to be able to help you in the most efficient way. Thank you!

Comment: Paste your function here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not being multiplied. You echoed `$key`, which is (as your comments indicate) `3`. You then echoed `$data[$key]['ID'][0]`, which is `6`. Hence, `36`.